# How to implement progress bar control like in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, drawing, progress-bar, nsbutton

I'd like to implement a control similar to Xcode progress bar:[image]

The bezel looks like a standard Textured Rounded button, but my problem is if I subclass NSButton and override drawing code I don't know where bezel edges are. They are some pixels off from the control bounds. This is how my button looks if I fill bounds with blue color before calling NSButton drawing code:[image]

My concern is if I just hardcode these margins then they may change with system updates and progress bar will look out of place. Maybe I'm missing some obvious way to implement this?

Comment: Does it have to be a button? Could this not be solved, by creating a custom view, with a progressbar at the bottom and one (or more) labels? If you create a view, you always knows the bounds and can ensure the layout is correct.

Comment: @JensPeter If it's not button then I need to reimplement all Texture Rounded button behaviour (like greying out when window in not focused, shadows etc.) plus I still do not understand how to draw that bezel. Seems not so easy to me.